# .NET Web API cannot be exposed/run

Tags: c#, .net, windows-server-2012-r2

I cannot run a Web API project on .NET 5 (tried .NET Core 3.1 before, the same) with the default template of WeatherForecast on my Windows Server 2012R2 (virtual) machine. The host creation is just stuck on `hostBuilder.Build()`.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start");
        var hostBuilder = CreateHostBuilder(args);
        Console.WriteLine("hostBuilder created");
        var host = hostBuilder.Build();
        Console.WriteLine("host created");
        host.Run();
        Console.WriteLine("host run");
    }
...
```

so the output is

```
Start
hostBuilder created
```

No errors.
I used different ways to run the code: VS 2019, Rider and CMD which all execute pretty much the same command `dotnet WebApplication.dll`.

The same code works on Linux Mint 20.1 Ulysaa (based on Ubuntu 20.04) without any problem.

Any idea what may be wrong with the Windows Environment?

Comment: A 2012R2 is a server and you have limited access to the machine unless you are an Admin.  If you are running from VS you do not automatically have Admin privilege.    You need to right click on VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: I am an Admin there (the local vm) and tried this trick as well. Did not help.

Comment: Do you see a runtime for aspnet core 5 installed if you run this on the server? `dotnet --list-runtimes`

Comment: Is application terminating?  The program should not hang.  I think you may be getting an exception.  Put a try/catch around the code.

Comment: @jdweng `dotnet --list-runtimes` returns many items including ones with version 5
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.26
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.26, 3.1.12, 3.1.13, 5.0.4 
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9, 2.1.26, 3.1.12, 3.1.13, 5.0.4 
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.12, 3.1.13, 5.0.4

Comment: Is application terminating? No.
The program should not hang. it is.
I think you may be getting an exception. then it would fail.
Put a try/catch around the code. unnecessary.

Comment: Try updating the Kernal in the mobile device.

Comment: "in the mobile device" how can it be related to the problem with the windows server environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I run code from a shared folder (with the drive letter in the path like Z:\solution) attached to my virtual (VirtulaBox) machine. All permissions were set to maximum privilege but still for some unknown reason .NET does not like handle this (may be due to symlynks?).